# JCheckBox mnemonic without transferring focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, mnemonics

As per title, is it possible to change a `JCheckBox` selection state using a *mnemonic key* without transferring the focus to the component?

Current behavior as per GIF.
The wanted behavior would be the focus remaining on the "Type" text field.

[image]

Comment: With the standard JCheckBox you can only achieve this with `setFocusable(false);` - but then you can no longer use the tab key to select the checkbox and then press the space key to toggle it.

Comment: @ThomasKläger if only I could intercept the mnemonic event. But I couldn't find a way

Comment: @ThomasKläger btw, workarounds are ok.

Comment: Instead of using a mnemonic you can use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: @camickr is it still possible to highlight the "fake mnemonic" letter on ALT with your strategy?

Comment: Does `setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(..)` work? If not, then maybe try to use HTML for the text. Then you can use the underline tag for the "B".

Comment: @camickr I've posted another answer, could you give your opinion?

Comment: Whatever works for you. Thomas's solution  seems simpler since both involve extending JCheckBox. My solution was a suggestion was a solution what would not involve extending a component so it could be used on any AbstractButton (JButton, JCheckBox, JRadioButton). In any case, it would be nice if your suggestion was posted as an [mre] so other could use the solution. We don't know what the UIUtilities method does.

Comment: @camickr the fact is the other solution, while it works, introduces mutable state, while overriding key bindings seems more focused on that single thing. The static method returns ALT or whatever key is assigned to the mnemonic system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the mnemonic is registered as a key binding, in the scope of

```
JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
```

---

See `BasicButtonListener#updateMnemonicBinding`

---

We can simply override the key binding actions with our own ones.

```kotlin
private class MnemonicCheckBox : JCheckBox(...) {
  override fun setMnemonic(mnemonic: Int) {
    super.setMnemonic(mnemonic)

    if (mnemonic != 0) {
      overrideMnemonicActions()
    }
  }

  private fun overrideMnemonicActions() {
    val mnemonicMask = UIUtilities.getSystemMnemonicKeyMask()
    val altGraphDownMask = InputEvent.ALT_GRAPH_DOWN_MASK

    getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).apply {
      // Pressed
      put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(mnemonic, mnemonicMask), "mnemonicPressed")
      put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(mnemonic, mnemonicMask or altGraphDownMask), "mnemonicPressed")

      // Released
      put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(mnemonic, mnemonicMask, true), "mnemonicReleased")
      put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(mnemonic, mnemonicMask or altGraphDownMask, true), "mnemonicReleased")
    }

    actionMap.apply {
      put("mnemonicPressed", object : AbstractAction() {
        override fun actionPerformed(event: ActionEvent) {
          model.isArmed = true
          model.isPressed = true
        }
      })
      put("mnemonicReleased", object : AbstractAction() {
        override fun actionPerformed(event: ActionEvent) {
          model.isPressed = false
          model.isArmed = false
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

To maintain the semantic expressed in `BasicButtonListener.Actions`, we have overridden both the `pressed` and `released` actions to change the `ButtonModel` state.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem are these lines from the [BasicButtonListener.Actions](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonListener.java#L297):

```
        if (key == PRESS) {
            ButtonModel model = b.getModel();
            model.setArmed(true);
            model.setPressed(true);
            if(!b.hasFocus()) {
                b.requestFocus();  // here it requests the focus
            }
        }
```

This is buried deep in the handling of the key binding for checkbox and this code was never meant to be customized.

A workaround would be to create your own class that extends `JCheckBox` and specifically doesn't request the focus while a key binding is processed:

```
public class MyCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

    private boolean requestFocusAllowed = true;

    public MyCheckBox() {
    }

    @Override
    public void requestFocus() {
        if (requestFocusAllowed) {
            super.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean processKeyBinding(KeyStroke ks, KeyEvent e, int condition, boolean pressed) {
        requestFocusAllowed = false;
        try {
            return super.processKeyBinding(ks, e, condition, pressed);
        } finally {
            requestFocusAllowed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems an idea similar to what camickr proposed in the comments. I suppose then the mnemonic is registered as keybinding, then what if I simply override it by registering a new one with the same key combination?

Comment: I've implemented what I mentioned above, feel free to give your opinion.